# XulRunner Not Compatible With SlimerJS on EC2

Tags: firefox, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, xulrunner

I'm trying to get SlimerJS up and running on my EC2 instance. I'm using an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS image. I installed firefox 41.0.1 and slimerjs 0.10.0pre. I have this working locally under pretty much identical circumstances. But when I try to launch this on the instance, I'm running into the error:

> Gecko error: it seems /home/ubuntu/slimerjs-0.10.0pre/xulrunner/xulrunner is not compatible with SlimerJS. See Gecko version compatibility.

In the application.ini file, it says:

```
[Gecko]
MinVersion=17.0.0
MaxVersion=41.*
```

Which I seem to be satisfying. I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: Did you try editing the file and chancing the `MaxVersion`? you can try to install older version.